# Passing an object through another object gets lost after the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to MVC4 and would probably appreciate some extra hand holding. Thanks in advance!

My project starts with a page strongly typed to TicketNumbers. On that view user chooses any number of the 50 checkboxes they want. Their selection is then passed to the next controller, GenerateCombosController.

```
    public class TicketNumbers
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<bool> Numbers { get; set; }

        public TicketNumbers() {
            Numbers = new List<bool>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) // default 50 for this example
            {
                Numbers.Add(false);
            }
        }

    }
```

In the GenerateCombosController, you see I'm using ReportCombinations to store the TicketNumbers that was just submitted. ReportCombinations rc is then passed to the view which is strongly typed to ReportCombinations.

```
    public ActionResult Index(TicketNumbers tn)
    {
        ReportCombinations rc = new ReportCombinations();
        rc.Numbers = tn;

        // ... plus some other default attributes for ReportCombinations rc

        return View(rc);
    }

    public ActionResult Submit(ReportCombinations rc)
    {        
        // do stuff here with rc's attributes
        // however rc.Numbers is null! :(

        return View("Index", rc);
    }
```

As you see, I want to Submit() the ReportCombinations object back to the same "Index" view, after the user has made some changes to ReportCombinations's attributes. I certainly get those altered attributes back however rc.Numbers comes back as null. >> Ideally the user will be able to keep submitting the same page to see different results when they change rc's attributes.

I've tried putting rc.Numbers attibutes (string Name and List Numbers) on the view as hidden values, but can't seem to get it right if that is what's required? Does using a ViewModel make a difference? I've also seen examples where TicketNumbers would be placed in session and brought back in the following method, but that is hardly at all graceful in my opinion.

Comment: show your Index.cshtml view!

Comment: specifically show how you are storing the Numbers property in the view.

Comment: Like I wrote. I don't have the answer for that otherwise I wouldn't be asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery and implement your own submit, there you can use `$.ajax()` to POST to the controller.

```
var yourObjectData = {  Name: "Name",  Numbers: [1,2,3,4,5]  }

$.ajax({
  url : "Controller/Submit",
  type: "POST",
  data : yourObjectData  ,
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
  {
    //data - response from server
  }
 });
```

Obviously there is more code to do but this is how you can manually construct the model object

Comment: What about ReportCombinations?

Comment: what are ReportCombinations?

Comment: ReportCombinations is another class which holds TicketNumbers and other attributes which have been omitted in the above question.

Comment: lol, so why would you ask me that.. =).  The point is your POST data needs to be a JSON object you can build via js.   Please upvote if this has been helpful... got bills to pay =)

Comment: ReportCombinations is the object to be posted back to Submit(). Please review the question.

Comment: all that matters is the JSON, if it has the same properties as the Model in the controller it will populate it.